# AngularJS ui-router not resolve service call

Tags: javascript, angularjs, service, resolve

I'm trying to use resolve feature in my ui-router state provider.
I've configured it as follows:

```
app.config(['$stateProvider', '$urlRouterProvider', '$locationProvider', function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $locationProvider) {
...
$stateProvider.state('expositions', {
        url: '/Expositions',
        views: {
            "container": {
                templateUrl: '/views/expositions.html', 
                resolve: {
                    expositions: function ($http) {
                        return $http.get('/api/site/expositions').then(
                            function (response) {
                                console.log("DATA", response.data);
                                return response.data;
                            },
                            function (error) {
                                console.log("ERROR", error);
                            })
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    })
...
}
```

In this case when I click on expositions link the resolve is not called and the navigation is not performed: nothing happens.

I've also tried to configure this with a factory (a resources service) as follows:

```
app.config(['$stateProvider', '$urlRouterProvider', '$locationProvider', function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $locationProvider) {
...
$stateProvider.state('expositions', {
        url: '/Expositions',
        views: {
            "container": {
                templateUrl: '/views/expositions.html', 
                resolve: {
                    expositions: function (Resources) {
                        console.log("DATA", Resources);
                        return Resources.expositions();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    })
...
}
```

The resource service is defined in a separate file as follows:

**resourcesService.js**

```
(function () {
    'use strict';

    angular
        .module('site')
        .factory('Resources', ['$resource',
            function ($resource) {
                return $resource('/api/site/:action/:id', {}, {

                    ...

                    expositions: {
                        method: 'GET',
                        params: { action: "expositions" },
                        isArray: true
                        //transformResponse: function (data) {
                        //    return angular.fromJson(data).list
                        //}
                    },

                    ...
                });
            }
        ]);
})();
```

Also in this case nothing happens and the resolve function is not called.

What am I missing?

Thanks all in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try giving this

```
expositions: ['$http',function ($http) {
```

Something like this

```
resolve: {
                expositions: ['$http',function ($http) {
                    return $http.get('/api/site/expositions').then(
                        function (response) {
                            console.log("DATA", response.data);
                            return response.data;
                        }],
                        function (error) {
                            console.log("ERROR", error);
                        })
                }
```

Let me know if this worked